# Unisntalling Ubuntu from dual-boot windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, grubrescue, windows-10

**Reboot the computer.**

1. Go to bios. ***( How?)***
2. Set the boot media to CD/DVD
3. Put the windows 7 DVD(or recovery disk)in to the drive. ***(I'm using windows 10 and I don't have either DVD or USB, would upgrading to windows 10 pro fix this problem below?)***

**Problem:**

I have removed Ubuntu and GRUB partitions, uninstalled Ubuntu from
    my programs. Now every time I boot my PC it takes me to a command
    prompt window which gives me 5 seconds to select OS that I want to
    boot with. I can select windows 10 and use it perfectly. Since I
    have removed all Ubuntu, how can I eliminate this detour to command
    window? would upgrading to windows 10 pro fix this problem?

Comment: can you go to bios and check which is the first on the list of boot options. It should be windows boot manager.

Comment: Getting into your BIOS setup depends on your computer. Dells use F2 on startup, Toshiba uses F10 or TAB, MSI uses F11, HP uses F10 or F2. If you can boot into Windows, you can create a recovery disc from there. See here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive

Comment: This is a Ubuntu specific forum. Not the best place to ask this question. Anyway, look for EasyBCD. It's a Windows program to recover the Windows Bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, EasyBCD could solve the problem. You'll need to overwrite the MBR using the program, assuming you can still boot into Windows from GRUB.

Failing that, you can create a bootable USB drive/DVD using the Media Creation Tool included in the Windows 10 installation. You'll need to start up through your newly-created recovery drive, and from there you'll need to click "Repair your computer".

You can initiate the automatic startup repair (which I recommend), or open up a command prompt and use the "bootrec" utility to rewrite the MBR. The command is as follows:

```
$ bootrec /fixmbr
```

Please let us know if you're still having trouble after exhausting the above options.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the GRUB boot manager (command prompt window you said you were seeing) from your computer by overwriting the MBR.

Simply boot up Windows and open a command prompt by

- press the Windows key on your keyboard
- type `cmd`
- right click "Command Prompt" in the results that appeared, and select "Run as administrator"
- now type `bootrec /fixmbr` + Enter
- and then `bootrec /fixboot` + Enter

That should have reset your start-up sequence back.